# problem in xml or in the code i have written?

Tags: iphone, xml

I am parsing xml from this url:

http://www.pfizerpro.com/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/com.wyeth.conventioncalendar.XMLFeed

The coming xml is like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<calendar_items>
<item>
<id>355</id>
<title>ASH</title>
<description>52nd Annual American Society of Hematology Meeting & Exposition</description>
<link>http://www.hematology.org/Meetings/Annual-Meeting/</link>
<event_start>12/04/2010</event_start>
<event_end>12/07/2010</event_end>
<event_category_term>Oncology, Hematology</event_category_term>

<city>Orlando</city>
<state>FL</state>
</item>
<item>
<id>357</id>
<title>null</title>
<description>Society of Urologic Oncology 2010 Annual Meeting</description>
<link>http://www.societyofurologiconcology.org/meetings/default.aspx</link>
<event_start>12/08/2010</event_start>
<event_end>12/10/2010</event_end>

<event_category_term>Hematology, Genitourinary, HIV, Immunology, Infectious Disease, Inflammation, Irritable bowel syndrome, Metabolic & Endocrine, Musculoskeletal, Neuroscience, Nutrition & Vitamins, Oncology</event_category_term>
<city>Bethesda</city>
<state>MD</state>
</item>
</calendar_items>
```

I am using this code for parsing:--

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://www.pfizerpro.com/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/com.wyeth.conventioncalendar.XMLFeed"];

    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    [xmlParser setDelegate: self];

    BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

    if(success) {

        [actView stopAnimating];
        table_view.hidden = NO;
        [table_view reloadData];
        NSLog(@"No Errors");
    }
    else {

        NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");
        [actView stopAnimating];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Application cannot get data from internet.Check your internet connection." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
```

It always gives error..Why  this happenes.Url is working and the correct xml format is coming..

i am parsing the xmlfrom similar url ..:- http://www.pfizerpro.com/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/com.wyeth.medpage.DMLFeed

Where is the problem?? in coming xml or in the code i have written..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal `&`s in line 6 and 23 are errors in your XML file (and they are indeed present in the original XML feed as I have just checked). They need to be `&amp;` instead.

In general, the following characters need to be masked in normal XML text:

```
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
```

Comment: Thanks sir...it was the & that creating the problem...i have replaced & with and and it works...Thanks for the reply...

Comment: When you’re having trouble with XML, use `xmllint`. It’s a command-line utility available on your system. If you run `xmllint` against your XML data, it’ll show that the literal ampersand is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Hi
just to add on to this. We will also face problems when you are forming xml containing any of the above tags. The request will not be processed if your request has the above tags. I have faced this in my project.
In such case also we need to replace the tags with its corresponding special characters while forming the xml and send the request.